# Is it possible to plug dependency property framework to Winform or ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms

The dependency property framework is a general UI Framework that can be needed outside WPF. So is there a way to use it for Winforms or ASP.NET UI for example ?

Update: I mean can I declare a few namespaces and use dependency property framework in winforms and asp.net ?

Answer (score 3):

I vaguely remember trying to use Routed Events in my own non-WPF code, and it turned out to be a nightmare. Both Routed Events and Dependency Objects need to be owned by DependencyObjects, which in turn inherit from System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject. At the very least, it would be horribly ugly -- if not impossible.

I would suggest using [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) etc. instead if you can. It's a little more code per property since you need a backing field and to call the NotifyChanged event, but it's much more straightforward.

Comment: So you tried already :) Does it mean MS implementation of property dependency is rotten somewhere ?

Comment: Kind of... I think it has something to do with the fact that DependencyProperties rely on the Dispatcher to invoke OnPropertyChanged handlers. The Dispatcher is analogous to the Win32 message pump, except a lot more robust and efficient but WPF specific. I remember them saying either to me or to someone else that they considered making DependencyProperty/RoutedEvents a standard .NET thing, but eventually decided against it as it would be difficult to do correctly. One of those difficult tradeoffs, I guess. Code reuse is almost always -- but not always -- a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most .NET IoC containers and dependency injection frameworks work within the confines of the framework.

This means they can work with ASP.NET and Winforms.

If this is not what you are asking, can you please clarify your question? It is not entirely clear what you are asking.

---

In regards to dependency properties (now that I understand exactly what you are talking about):

You can use them in winforms and webforms, since these are also written in .NET. As you posted in your comment, yes, simply importing several namespaces should be enough.

Comment: I mean can I declare a few namespaces and use dependency property framework in winforms and asp.net ?

Comment: Will try then but seems Rei Miyasaka has tried and it was a nightmare :)

Answer (score 1):

What features of the dependency property sub-system after you after? If you're specifically after binding support, you could something like [Truss](http://truss.codeplex.com) as a general binding manager.

Comment: Thanks will also look at Truss